# No load data anymore except refresh action

Tags: android, android-fragments

I couldn't find a solution to my problem on the search engine, So i decided to ask here.

I have navigation tab with 3 fragments `fragmentA, fragmentB, fragmentC`. Each fragment load data from parsed data. i have opened fragment a and load data on listview, then i want to change to fragment b, and load the data too. but when i want to go back to fragmentA the fragment loads the data again.

I want my fragment are saving the loaded data before and when i refresh the fragment, the fragment load new data. An example app like a twitter or facebook. What i have to do? thanks for reading

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View Vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_kuliah, container, false);

    //Hashmap for ListView
    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    progress = (LinearLayout) Vi.findViewById(R.id.linlaHeaderProgress);

    ListView lv = (ListView) Vi.findViewById(R.id.list1);

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title))
                    .getText().toString();
            String email = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.publisher))
                    .getText().toString();
            String address = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description))
                    .getText().toString();
            //String thumb_url = ((ImageView))

            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity() ,SingleKuliahAct.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, email);
            in.putExtra(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
            startActivity(in);
            getActivity().overridePendingTransition( R.anim.left1, R.anim.left2 );
        }
    });
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    return Vi;
}


private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... args0) {

    // Creating service handler class instance
    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

    //getting JSON string from URL
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url_contacts, ServiceHandler.GET);

    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            // Getting JSON Array node
            contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);

                // tmp hashmap for single contact
                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                contact.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);

                // adding contact to contact list
                contactList.add(contact);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
    }

    return null;
    }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // Dismiss the progress dialog
    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    /*ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            getActivity(), contactList,
            R.layout.list_kuliah_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_ADDRESS}, new int[] { R.id.title,
                    R.id.publisher, R.id.description });

    ListView mView = (ListView) 
            getView().findViewById(R.id.list1);    
    mView.setAdapter(adapter);*/

    KuliahAdapter adapter;
    ListView List = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list1);
    adapter = new KuliahAdapter(getActivity(), contactList);
    List.setAdapter(adapter);

    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

above is my code on fragment kuliah (fragment A), and i have adapter for each fragment

```
public class KuliahAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public KuliahAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_kuliah_item, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.publisher); // artist name
    TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.description); // duration
    //TextView countcomment = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.countcomment); // duration
    //TextView countlikes = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.countlikes); // duration
    //TextView created = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.created); // created
    //ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image); // default image

    HashMap<String, String> contactList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    contactList = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(contactList.get(KuliahFragment.TAG_NAME));
    artist.setText(contactList.get(KuliahFragment.TAG_EMAIL));
    duration.setText(contactList.get(KuliahFragment.TAG_ADDRESS));
    //countcomment.setText(courses.get(KuliahFragment.TAG_COUNTCOMMENT));
    //countlikes.setText(courses.get(KuliahFragment.TAG_COUNTLIKES));
    //created.setText(courses.get(KuliahFragment.TAG_CREATED));
    //imageLoader.DisplayImage(courses.get(KuliahFragment.TAG_IMAGE), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
```

}

Comment: add code of what you are doing, then maybe it will be possible to understand what you need and help you

Comment: thanks to Bryan McLemore, i have added some code of my question.

Comment: can you help me royB, i was added some code. Thanks